# package 'tfrupee' failing in web link since update to MacTex 21

Tags: mactex

Environment. MacBook Air 2019, macOS 10.414.6 (patched to date), full MacTeX 2021 install

Since upgrading from MacTeX '20 to '21, using the `\rupee` macro provided by the `tfrupee` package fails *if* used in hypertext link. Previously, under older MacTeX versions it worked fine in body copy or in a link. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tfrupee}

\begin{document}

Inline use of \rupee \ symbol.

\href{http://www.example.com/index.html}{test}

%\href{http://www.example.com/\rupee.html}{\rupee}

End text.

\end{document}
```

The first text shows `\rupee` works in body copy and the first URL shows `\href` macros are working correctly. The second URL fails with the errors:

`Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa. \href{http://www.example.com/\rupee.html}`

`Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa. ...ttp://www.example.com/\rupee.html}{\rupee}`

Presumably one error for each use within the `\href{}` section. The log shows this for each of the above:

`! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa. <to be read again>  1 l.13 \href{http://www.example.com/\rupee.html} {\rupee} You meant to type ## instead of #, right? Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.`

What am I doing wrong? Does the 2021 MacTex need some extra setting?

Comment: I can't believe that that ever worked. Perhaps you had some local setting that provided a definition for hyperref.

Comment: I need to cite/use a URL that inconveniently uses a Rupee symbol. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: hyperref currently assumes that the url is percent encoded. You can't use non-ascii chars, you wouldn't get a valid url from it.

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by [@Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) second comment above, I tried using the Unicode number value for ₹ which is %u20B9. If I use this:

```
\href{https://www.example.com/\%u20B9.html}{\rupee}
```

It passes LaTeX processing without error and gives a working link. But, testing using my web domain (not example.com) the `₹.html` doesn't load but instead I see
`%25u20B9.html` which results in a 404.

Taking a different tack I used https://onlineunicodetools.com/url-encode-unicode to convert `₹` to a UTF-8 encoded<sup>†</sup> string `%e2%82%b9` allowing this code:

```
\href{https://www.example.com/\%E2\%82\%B9.html}{\rupee}
```

which works in LaTex and loads a page rendering in the browser location bar as `₹.html`. So the fixed MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tfrupee}

\begin{document}

Inline use of \rupee \ symbol.

\href{http://www.example.com/index.html}{test}

\href{https://www.example.com/\%E2\%82\%B9.html}{\rupee}
% opens URL at 'example.com/₹.html`

End text.

\end{document}
```

So, I hope this helps others in a similar bind. And kudos to [@Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) for setting mme on the right track.

Learning point, for the less code-experienced like myself, not all '%-codes' are equal!

†. At least I think it's UTF-8 encoding! Commenters - feel free to correct me if wrong, so as to help later readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the definition of `\rupee` protected, then it sort of works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\protected\def\rupee{{\usefont{U}{tfrupee}{m}{n}\char124}}

\begin{document}

Inline use of \rupee \ symbol.

\href{http://www.example.com/index.html}{test}

\href{http://www.example.com/\rupee.html}{\rupee}

End text.

\end{document}
```

Of course this won't make a legal URL and the link will point nowhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\protected\def\rupee{{\usefont{U}{tfrupee}{m}{n}\char124}}
\begingroup\catcode`\%=12
\gdef\urlrupee{%E2%82%B9}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

Inline use of \rupee \ symbol.

\href{http://www.example.com/index.html}{test}

\href{http://www.example.com/\urlrupee.html}{\rupee}

End text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I click on the hyperlink, my browser goes to

[image]

Explanation: the Unicode for INDIAN RUPEE SIGN is U+20B9, which is `0xE282B9` in UTF-8.

Protecting `\rupee` is not necessary for the example, but I'd recommend it anyway.